# How can I use pragma weak with namespaced functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

This works:

`test1.h`

```
namespace funcs {
  extern "C" {
    void a();
    void b();
    void c();
  }
}
```

`test1.cpp`

```
namespace funcs {
  void (*all[])() = {a, b, c};
}
extern "C" void hang() {
  while (true);
}

#pragma weak a = hang
#pragma weak b = hang
#pragma weak c = hang
```

---

But this doesn't:

`test1.h`

```
namespace funcs {
    void a();
    void b();
    void c();
}
```

`test1.cpp`

```
namespace funcs {
  void (*all[])() = {a, b, c};
}
void hang() {
  while (true);
}

#pragma weak funcs::a = hang
#pragma weak funcs::b = hang
#pragma weak funcs::c = hang
```

I think this is due to `#pragma weak` requiring mangled names. Is there any way I can get the compiler (GCC 4.7.3) to emit the mangled names for me?

Answer (score 2):

There is no stable way to demangle in g++, reason is, that mangling rules aren't portable even between different g++ versions.

Also, `#pragma weak` is C-extension (declared in `gcc/c-family/c-pragma.c` file) and don't normally work with C++

In terms of GCC development, correct solution is to provide code for something like `#pragma cpp-weak` and commit to gcc, but it seems to be rather complex task. You may make an improvement request in GCC bugzilla, may be somebody will help.

You may also want to declare assembler labels for C++ functions by yourself, and to make weak references for them, like:

```
namespace funcs {
    void a()  __asm__("mya");
    void b()  __asm__("myb");
    void c()  __asm__("myc");
}

namespace funcs {
  void (*all[])() = {a, b, c};
}

extern void hang() __asm__("myhang");
void hang() {
  while (true);
}

#pragma weak mya = myhang
#pragma weak myb = myhang
#pragma weak myc = myhang
```

But I'm not sure, that it is much better for you, then "extern C" specification.